# How can i update sqllite dynamically?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have set app my sql lite database for my app. Is there any way to update the database without republishing the app? For example i want to add a new user in the sqlite database. Do i have to upgrade the database version on my app and publish it again? Is the remote database the only solution for dynamic android database?

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood, you want "deploy" a new db for your app. You can do that but you need root access because in other case you don't have permission. Something like:

> adb push yourNewDB data/data/this.is.your.package/databases

Then enter in shell:

> adb shell

Then kill the process for your App:

> ps
>   kill pid

Comment: I have published the app in google play console. Is there any way to update the app's database or do i have to publish the app every time i make a change?

Comment: You can, but the question is how are you going to tell all users that there is a new database model??

Comment: @luispuli Overly complicated. Needs root and ADB access. And why do users need to know there is a new DB model? Do you get notified when WhatsApp changes its DB model?

Comment: Yes you are right @m0skit0, that process could be done only for testing/developing purposes.Well, WhatsApp forces you update from market if you want continue using it.

Comment: For sure there is standard way to do that as you can see in the second part of the question: "Do i have to upgrade the database version on my app and publish it again?"

Answer (score 0):

You can remotely provide updates to your DB via an online service. This could provide whole new DB file for file replace or alternatively provide delta CRUD updates via xml or json. But you will need to code your update method into the app before publishing.

Comment: DB is not bundled into the APK.

Comment: Oh sorry, you mean you have made the DB in code? I thought you meant how to update a DB which you have provided in the assets folder. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to upgrade your app without republishing it unless you have an update system integrated on your app.

The simplest (and standard) solution is to republish and upgrade your DB version number, then the `onUpgrade()` callback will get called. There you should check the current DB and upgrade as required. Following your example, you just have to check if that user exists and if not create it.